# Adding multiple backgrounds with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, function, background-image

I'm trying to do an accordion with jQuery. When you mouseover, it is supposed to change color to orange but also keep the background image. The same thing on mouseleave, but I can't get it on. How do I add the multiple backgrounds with jQuery?

This is the code I am using:

```
$(".wrap-faq").on("mouseover", hoverFaq);

function hoverFaq() {
  $(this).css("background", "#f7941e");
  $(this).css("backgroundImage", "url(...img/bkg_leer_artic.png) center repeat");
}

$(".wrap-faq").on("mouseleave", unHoverFaq);

function unHoverFaq() {
  $(this).css("background", "#e0e0e0");
  $(this).css("backgroundImage", "url(...img/bkg_leer_artic.png) center repeat");
}
```

I am also trying to add an `active` class when you click on the button, so it keeps orange, but this doesn't work either.

jQuery:

```
$(".wrap-faq ").on("click", accordion);
function accordion() {
  if (!$(this).hasClass("active")) {
    $(".wrap-faq ").next().slideUp();
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
    $(".wrap-faq ").removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
}
```

CSS:

```
.active {
background:#f7941e url("../img/bkg_leer_artic.png") center repeat;
}

.wrap-faq {
background:#e0e0e0 url("../img/bkg_leer_artic.png") center repeat;
margin-bottom:2px;
cursor:pointer;
}
```

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xtatanx/3zvgY/5/

Comment: Can you look over and edit your text for a second, I think you mean "can't" when you say "can" and there are various other confusing words/ sentences.

Comment: If you set up a www.jsFiddle.net it will make solving your issue much faster. For some of your questions, we kinda need to see the html too.

Comment: @watson Agreed, and agreed.

Comment: Thanks for the jsFiddle, in your hoverFaq() function you have a typo ... instead of, I am assuming, ../

Comment: what is a typo?, i amm sorry my english is not that good xD

Comment: I think it stands for typographical error, it just means a spelling mistake, or you pressed the wrong key while typing.

Comment: i just check, but everything seems to be ok on the typographic :/

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3zvgY/6/)

To keep the orange, you needed to add !important to your rule to override the inline mouseout style:

```
.faq.active {
    background: #f7941e !important; 
}
```

As far as the background-images go, you need to put them on some photo-hosting site and then refer to their link from that hosting site on the jsFiddle, so that we can see them there.

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of people manipulating elements with `.css()`.  This can be frustrating and difficult to troubleshoot since all those change are applied to inline style.

Instead, try using `toggleClass()`, `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`.  Then your styles are defined in a format that's much more organized and easier to manipulate, rather than adding multiple `.css()` functions.  And since you already have those styles pre-defined in your CSS, I don't see why you would use `.css()` anyway.

Comment: ive been trying in all ways, but even using add class nothins happins, alsays erase my background image!

Comment: @watson -  ...maybe?  I mean, why have the styles defined elsewhere if you're going to manipulate the elements with `.css()`?  Seems pointless.

Comment: I agree with your sentiment but this would be better suited as a comment - it doesn't address the question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm struggling a bit to understand exactly what you're trying to do, but I think you're wanting to change the background colour whilst still retaining the background image.

This fiddle shows how I'd do it (<strike>apologies for the image</strike> - actually, I don't apologise for the image, SuperDog rules).
http://jsfiddle.net/Town/MtFa4/

You're using `background`, which is a shortcut for all of the `background-` CSS declarations, therefore when you do

```
$(this).css("background", "#e0e0e0");
```

You're overwriting the `background-image` declaration.

Comment: thankc you very much, i just achieves my purppose using important!...but ill keep in mind your fiddle and ill save it!

Comment: `!important` is handy, but should be used sparingly.  Once you have a style defined as `!important` you lose a lot of the C in CSS! :)  Here's an article about it: http://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/